# Maximum Simultaneous Connection on ADODB.connection?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, ms-access, adodb

I plan to download stock price for 1400 stock, every 10 seconds. the download was perfect and only consumes couple of millisecond.

The next step is writing 1400 records into 1400 separate mdb file (i.e. each mdb file using 1 adodb.connection) every 10 seconds. I tried to improve the performance by using multiple thread (not exceeding CPU thread count) to do the job, each thread responsible for some connections.

Soonly I realize the performance was not improve as expected (more thread doesn't improve performance), and the CPU load does not increase with more threads,
which suggest that the bottleneck was in the adodb.connection object. However,
the performance was improved by using 2 separate connection string alternatively (different provider), as follows.

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=xxx

Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=xxx
```

I also tried to make the threads into complied .exe file and calling them with multiple instance simultaneously (i.e. 12 instances with 12 threads CPU) and the performance was improved significantly 
(and the CPU load was started to max out as instance increases)

Is that the provider bottle-necked the whole process?

Or is there any proper way to 'duplicate' the provider so that the performance can be increased?

I don't want the program execute in a way by calling .exe which seems hard to managed

I also notice that the total simultaneous connection in a VB.net project cannot exceed 64 or otherwise  following error message pop-up:

> Run time error -2147467259(80004005) Automation error,Unspecified error

Any way to increase the 64 connection limit?

Comment: IMO, you should re-think the *1400 separate mdb files* and the MS-Access database as storage, in this scenario.

Comment: Connections are very light objects and usually don't make any performance problems. If you could provide some code of storage operation, we may able to help.

Comment: Hi jimi, understand that MS-access is not a proper solution to this scenario but due to ease of speed, maintenance and backup so i choose to.....

Comment: Hi Mr Rahmanifard, i just use standard adodb.connection and adodb.recordset to manipulate the datatables, which is perfect for under 64 mdb files. I think the way to solve is either 1) increase the simultaneous connection 2) 'duplicate' the provider, or any recommendation? I am new to this forum and don't know how to post code.

Comment: `1,400` records every 10 sec. → `12,096,000` records per day → `362,880,000` per month. IMO, you should re-think your storage strategy, also considering that you cannot open and operate 1,400 connections. Unless you discard this data every end of the day. Then you may use a MS-Acces file. One file. If you need to keep (and use) the data, you need something else completely.

Comment: The queries should be open connection, do query, dispose of connection. Using the [`Using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) construct for the connections will take care of that for you. Connection pooling will take care of keeping the creation of connections efficient behind the scenes.

Comment: *writing 1400 records into 1400 separate mdb* ... This is not how you work with databases. No matter which backend you use.

Comment: Pushing system for something unneeded is not the best way to tackle a problem.Simply calculate the amount of data you are going to need and make a choice...if you estimate that 2GB is going to get quickly consumed then probably is a good idea to change your BE (Sqlite ?) and of course not 1400 tables..just a table holding the OHLC and probably a bit normalization (a table for stocks,dates,OHLC data should be enough)

Comment: Hi Andre, I am trying to push the limit of Access, currently I am using a 6 core 12 thread i7-8700 CPU, the total time consumed for data grab and store was under 5 second for 1400 record. if i can keep all 1400 connection open, I think the time can further decreased much.

Comment: Hi Jimi, the stock market was only operate 5.5 hour per day, the record per day was around 16Mil, but i have run 3 days and end up with around 3MByte per file, it still consider a very light database file for fast access (I need to keep it small to allow faster SQL query for later process). you have guessed right the file will be discarded and re-create every day, so each file will be around 1MB by the end of day. indeed the collected data will be backup to another .mdb file which keeps all daily and minute OHLC data, Technical indicators etc... when market was closed.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to launch each task as a separate thread in .net. The REAL problem here is while you could attempt to heavy thread your code, with 6 cores, you only going to get 6 times the increase.
The major bottle neck? Even if you were to keep all 6 cores running a thead? You likly only see a small % of processor useage! But why?

Well, while .net (or even  VBA) can execute easy a billion instructions per second? Well the issue becomes the huge time to open a file.

If you open a file?
Then the OS comes into play big time here.
The OS will check permissions.
The OS checks if file exists. 
Then it checks if someone else has it open.
Virus software then might scan the file or do other things.
then the ACE/JET data engine in Access starts to go to work.
It check if open by someone else (and if yes, then open file in multi-user mode)
If not multi user mode, open file for single user high speed use.
Now, I can insert about 100+ more steps here.

But, ALL OF THE ABOVE steps are NOT your code! All of the above is occurring and being done by the OS - all your code can do is WAIT and WAIT for all of the above to finish. Because the above means you using the file system, then your code going to sit around and wait for a long time. As a result, you be waiting for directory information and all kinds of things to load. And these things take a lot of time. So, the CPU  will be waiting for input/output, and waiting for file directories to load, then to scan them. So, everything becomes input/output (I/O) bound, and not processor bound. As a result, you will see a VERY low % of CPU usage, since really everything is spending it times waiting for the file to open and load. The time to open and get a file handle and to start the data to flow into a access database? Well, I did some benchmarks years ago. Its around a 100,000 records of data flow. In other words, the time to open ONE database file is about the same time if the database has been already opened and you want to save 100,000 rows of data!

So, if you open 10 databases? Well, if you had one open already, you could write out 1 million rows of data in the SAME TIME to one database!! Now, with better OS and file systems, muti cores?

Well the 100,000 rows of data = open one database file rule? It might have changed, and things might be MUCH better. But we are still at LEAST 10,000 rows of data writing to a table as being the SAME cost and time to open ONE database!!!

You certainly could open 1400 files (databases) on startup. However, I have to think somthing is serious wrong with the design and approach being used here. It not at all clear of  the overall goal, but 1400 databases does not seem to be a workable solution, and throwing more CPU's, and more threading at this problem is not going to yield much of a viable solution. While you might get 1400 threads, the OS file system is going to cue up theses requests and deal with them not  in such a great parallel fashion.

Worse yet? The code for the access datbase engine (ACE/JET) is 30+ years old. It is not managed code, and it certainly not threaded code. However, if you create 1400 seperate instsncs of your file opens, then they should play nice, but sharing the connection object etc. will not work. So you need 1400 seperate connection objects, and 1400 sperate file opens. So, if you build a class, and create 1400 instances, and then launch each one as a seperate thread from .net? This should work, but as noted, with 6 cores, you only going to get 6 actual threads running and working on this problem at the same time. And each of those threads will still be bottle necked by the OS which will que up the file opening and file management parts. I don't know how many file threads that windows (say version 10) allows, but the file system is still going to remain signficant bottleneck here if you do manage to get 1400 files open.

As I stated, the cost of opening a database is at LEAST the cost of flowing 10,000 rows of data into a already open database ready for data flowing.

So, unless you going to open 1400 files at start, then it will not be from a performance point of view to open so many files DURING this process - it has to be a one time deal.

You really then need to open one database file, and  inside have 1400 tables (since that is only still one file being opened).

But, then again, in place of 1400 files? Why not add one column to the one data table that distinguishes the 1400 tables, and now we all the way down to one file and one table.

You have to give further details why one table can't be used here. It likely your best choice and solution. You could consider 1400 tables in ONE database, but 1400 databases being opened is really not a practical idea here at all.

Comment: Hi Albert, thank for your detailed reply, before i posted my design of 1400 mdb file, i already expected people will ask "why not use a proper database system". I understand that i am doing something "abnormal" to workaround this, but since this is my hobbit and not a commercial project which have dead-line to complete, and secondly, using .exe method i really got significant improvement in this case, the time need was way down from 20 second using 1 instance to around 4 second in 6 instance, indeed my target will be end up with 3000 .mdb files.

Comment: go straight to your question, i have asked "Any way to increase the 64 connection limit?", I really understand the overhead for opening a connection was large, especially 1400 files. Why i using one .mdb file per stock? because after I write the OHLC record, I will have technicial indicator to calculate and write back to the database, and finally, executing couple of SQL query to find if the stock was giving signal for buy sell, I am going to write a system that trade in a 10 second interval, so I need to minimize the query time, as i replied to jimi, the everyday mdb file will be only 1 Mb.

Comment: If using a single database, i think the query time will be exponential if considering a 1Mb x 1400 stock database file ( that was somewhat 1.4 GB in size). Also in my understanding, ADO w/ access is the fastest database architecture. I planned to upgrade my computer to 3950x later which have 32 threads, i expected the computation power will be around 3x (5928 vs 15401 marks in geekbench 5), so that i can done the thing within 10 seconds